# Is there a way to prevent implicit static_casts when calling a function?

Tags: c++

C++11 adds this.

```
int x;
unsigned int y{ x }; // ERROR
```

Is it possible to enable something like this.

```
int x;
void f(unsigned int y);
f(x); //ERROR
```

Compiler: VC++ 2013

Comment: You are getting error, or you want compiler to give error?

Comment: @pranitkothari, I want the compiler to give an error or a warning.

Comment: Do not try to change compiler's behavior (because it may be not easily possible). You need to take care of your code, yourself.

Comment: Please add which compiler you are using so someone may help.

Comment: Willing to do `f({x})`?

Comment: Your question text currently does not reflect your title question... apparently you only want to forbid narrowing conversions.

Comment: In `gcc` you can use `-Werror=conversion`. This will give you an error on conversion during compilation. Not sure about VC++...

Comment: Voted to close because it is unclear what you are asking

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: I think it's clear enough.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit so you should be able to say what he is asking.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: He wishes to set his compiler such that implicit conversions for function arguments of built-in integral types is disabled.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Does he want `unsigned short x; f(x);` be an error or not? The corresponding snippet analogous to the first case, `unsigned short x; unsigned int y{ x };` is well-formed. I remarked this yesterday and the question was not yet clarified.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ([live example](http://ideone.com/zbbcNP)):

```
template <
    typename T,
    typename = typename std::enable_if <std::is_same <T, unsigned int>{}>::type
>
void f(T x) { }
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I think OP's author wants more of a compiler switch to forbid implicit casts.

Comment: I retracted my downvote because your reply is otherwise correct. Whether it is an answer can't yet be said.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no compiler switch or other general setting to do that. Implicit conversions are part of the language, and cannot be disabled in the general case for built-in types. The closest you can get is a user-defined wrapper class with only `explicit` constructors, or applying some template meta-hackery to the function you're trying to call (as in [iavr's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22579420/560648)).

The premise of your question appears to conflate *implicit conversions* with the special case of *narrowing* conversions. The following:

```
int x = 0;
unsigned int y{ x };
```

is *not* an error. You [may get a warning about the *potential* narrowing conversion](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58052224e82b9a59), and this warning may be turned into an error (with GCC's `-Werror`, [for example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f36aea5f27b658f2)), but this is not new in C++11 and it does not inherently prohibit the conversion.

[The program is only ill-formed if you *actually* cause a narrowing conversion.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8579314/560648) Again, this is specific to the value involved and is not a general rule about implicit conversions.