# freeimage 3.17 library build failing on Mac OS X: fails with C++11 narrowing error... any ideas?

Tags: c++11, osx-yosemite, freeimage

With not having any understanding of C++ (I'm teaching myself Swift), I'm struggling a bit to get around this one - but ideally would love to be able to expose some of the functionality in the FreeImage library in my project.

It appears that only one module is generating any errors: dcraw_common.cpp - and the lines in error are those from the following entry list where there is a value of 0x80 or above. From the investigations I've done, it would appear that these values are too large for a signed char (max 128?), yet the list also includes negative numbers, and so it can't use an unsigned char.

Any help would be most gratefully received.

Here's an example of the error message generated by the make process:

```
    Source/LibRawLite/./internal/dcraw_common.cpp:4543:19: error: constant expression evaluates to 136 which cannot be narrowed to type 'signed char'
    [-Wc++11-narrowing]
        +1,-1,+1,+1,0,0x88, +1,+0,+1,+2,0,0x08, +1,+0,+2,-1,0,0x40,
                      ^~~~
```

And here's the code:

```
    void CLASS vng_interpolate()
    {
      static const signed char *cp, terms[] = {
        -2,-2,+0,-1,0,0x01, -2,-2,+0,+0,1,0x01, -2,-1,-1,+0,0,0x01,
        -2,-1,+0,-1,0,0x02, -2,-1,+0,+0,0,0x03, -2,-1,+0,+1,1,0x01,
        -2,+0,+0,-1,0,0x06, -2,+0,+0,+0,1,0x02, -2,+0,+0,+1,0,0x03,
        -2,+1,-1,+0,0,0x04, -2,+1,+0,-1,1,0x04, -2,+1,+0,+0,0,0x06,
        -2,+1,+0,+1,0,0x02, -2,+2,+0,+0,1,0x04, -2,+2,+0,+1,0,0x04,
        -1,-2,-1,+0,0,0x80, -1,-2,+0,-1,0,0x01, -1,-2,+1,-1,0,0x01,
        -1,-2,+1,+0,1,0x01, -1,-1,-1,+1,0,0x88, -1,-1,+1,-2,0,0x40,
        -1,-1,+1,-1,0,0x22, -1,-1,+1,+0,0,0x33, -1,-1,+1,+1,1,0x11,
        -1,+0,-1,+2,0,0x08, -1,+0,+0,-1,0,0x44, -1,+0,+0,+1,0,0x11,
        -1,+0,+1,-2,1,0x40, -1,+0,+1,-1,0,0x66, -1,+0,+1,+0,1,0x22,
        -1,+0,+1,+1,0,0x33, -1,+0,+1,+2,1,0x10, -1,+1,+1,-1,1,0x44,
        -1,+1,+1,+0,0,0x66, -1,+1,+1,+1,0,0x22, -1,+1,+1,+2,0,0x10,
        -1,+2,+0,+1,0,0x04, -1,+2,+1,+0,1,0x04, -1,+2,+1,+1,0,0x04,
        +0,-2,+0,+0,1,0x80, +0,-1,+0,+1,1,0x88, +0,-1,+1,-2,0,0x40,
        +0,-1,+1,+0,0,0x11, +0,-1,+2,-2,0,0x40, +0,-1,+2,-1,0,0x20,
        +0,-1,+2,+0,0,0x30, +0,-1,+2,+1,1,0x10, +0,+0,+0,+2,1,0x08,
        +0,+0,+2,-2,1,0x40, +0,+0,+2,-1,0,0x60, +0,+0,+2,+0,1,0x20,
        +0,+0,+2,+1,0,0x30, +0,+0,+2,+2,1,0x10, +0,+1,+1,+0,0,0x44,
        +0,+1,+1,+2,0,0x10, +0,+1,+2,-1,1,0x40, +0,+1,+2,+0,0,0x60,
        +0,+1,+2,+1,0,0x20, +0,+1,+2,+2,0,0x10, +1,-2,+1,+0,0,0x80,
        +1,-1,+1,+1,0,0x88, +1,+0,+1,+2,0,0x08, +1,+0,+2,-1,0,0x40,
        +1,+0,+2,+1,0,0x10
      }, chood[] = { -1,-1, -1,0, -1,+1, 0,+1, +1,+1, +1,0, +1,-1, 0,-1 };
    ...
```

Comment: You could rewrite 0x88 as -120, and similarly for all such numbers that you get errors for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++11 prevents ['narrowing conversions'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434140/narrowing-conversions-in-c0x-is-it-just-me-or-does-this-sound-like-a-breakin) like that. Early versions of C++ would accept them. I think this patch to the source of `dcraw_common.cpp` should fix it.

https://gist.github.com/conchurnavid/ac19c8e882f1835f0310

There's a duplicate question here. [Building FreeImage 3.16.0 for Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24436945/building-freeimage-3-16-0-for-android)

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I applied the patch, but I'm still getting one line in error. 
In class adobe_coeff:
-    short black, maximum, trans[12];
+    ushort black, maximum;
+    short trans[12];
But in 3.17 source, the line to be replaced reads:
int t_black, t_maximum, trans[12];
I replaced this with the 2 replacement lines, but the following error appears:
error: duplicate member 'imgdata'
ushort black, maximum; (indicating maximum as the error source).
I also tried the make without replacing this line, but the C++11 narrowing error appeared.
Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0):

The most usable solution I found to this issue was the following GitHub posting: https://github.com/danoli3/FreeImage. Here some kind soul appears to have successfully built the 3.17.0 library and uploaded it. I've found that works just fine.

Please bear in mind however that it's been built with a hard-coded path of `/opt/local/lib` - which may be an issue when you come to implementation, since your app will be looking for it there, not bundled with the app. I did find this [LiveCode](http://lessons.livecode.com/m/4071/l/15029-linking-an-osx-external-bundle-with-a-dylib-library) post aided my understanding in that regard a lot.

Hope this helps.