# Primer says error but code works fine on GCC

Tags: c++, c++11

This code works fine:

```
    double a =2.12345;
    int b{a};            // According to primer error: narrowing conversion required
    int c(a);            //This is fine
```

Is it something which I am missing? For me when a float/double is assigned to int the values on left of the decimal are printed (floor value). Primer says error.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434140/narrowing-conversions-in-c0x-is-it-just-me-or-does-this-sound-like-a-breakin

Comment: Try building it with `g++ -std=c++14` so you don't get the gnu++14 extensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it something which I am missing?

The unfortunate detail of compilers deviating from the standard. GCC doesn't enforce it unless you tell it that it should. Try compiling with the `-pedantic-errors` option.

The primer isn't wrong, it's an ill-formed program according to the C++ standard alone. But compilers may choose to accept it as an extension, such is what GCC does.

Answer (score 0):

Some compilers (rightfully) enforce it by default. MacOSX clang for example would return an error:

`type 'double' cannot be narrowed to 'int' in initializer list [-Wc++11-narrowing]`

For GCC, the option `-Wconversion` should generate a warning.